# sort numeric column based on absolute values and scientific notation

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a file with positive numbers,negative numbers, and numbers in scientific notation, all in the same column. I want to sort it by the number's absolute value, considering the scientific notation.

For example, consider this file:

```
cat foo

7.70488617137843e-05  
-8.50387220311822
0.1
-3.3453262e-02
```

I have tried:

```
sort foo

0.1
-3.3453262e-02
7.70488617137843e-05
-8.50387220311822
```

This treats positive and negative numbers as the same (=absolute value, which I want); but ignores scientific notation.

.

```
sort -n foo

-8.50387220311822
-3.3453262e-02
0.1
7.70488617137843e-05
```

This respects positive and negative values, and ignores scientific notation. This is the opposite of what I want.

.

```
sort -g foo

-8.50387220311822
-3.3453262e-02
7.70488617137843e-05
0.1
```

This respects scientific notation (which I want), but also respects positive and negative values.

.

The output I want will look like:

```
7.70488617137843e-05
-3.3453262e-02
0.1
-8.50387220311822
```

This respects scientific notation, but treats positive and negative numbers the same.

I have read the sort documentation but I can't find an answer.

I use bash version 4.1.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/^-\(.*\)/\1-/' | sort -g | sed 's/^\(.*\)-$/-\1/'
```

The idea is to transform every negative number `-123` into `123-`, then sort numerically (which ignores the trailing `-`), then undo the transformation.

Comment: Thank you all. I choose this answer because it uses sed and sort, which I am a bit more familiarized with. Also, there is an explanation of what the code is doing. 
Regarding the code details, could someone elaborate on the meaning of this two expressions in sed: 1)  (.*) [with escaped () ] and 2) the $ symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `perl` solution because I think it is not so easy to do it in pure `bash`:

```
perl -e 'print sort { abs($a) <=> abs($b) } <>' foo
```

Comment: Thanks. this works too. Looks simple enough, but I no nothing of perl

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby -e 'puts (IO.readlines "sn.txt").sort_by { |e| e.to_f.abs }'
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. I have never heard of ruby before.

Comment: @Mau, Ruby is the greatest programming language ever.  (Ahem. Lol.) It's used for everything from command scripting to writing huge web applications. It's the language Rails is written in, and, along with Javascript, it's the one all those Rails developers are using.  It's one of the few *everything-is-an-object* and *object-based-from-day-1* languages.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the info!